# Sets question partitions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-partition

How do I check whether $F=\{\{a,b\},c\}$ is a partition of $E=\{a,b,c\}$?

Comment: What is your definition of a partition? Usually partitions are just putting some of the set into various boxes, loosely speaking. It should be clear inspection. And this is a partition.

Comment: @TheCount It's usually a problem that $a$ and $b$ are tucked away one layer "deeper" than $c$, though. So the box that is $F$ contains one box with $a$ and $b$ in it, and then a $c$ just lying freely around in there.

Comment: @Arthur Oh, I see what you mean. I didn't realize we were dealing with that level of pedantry, but yes, then, you are absolutely correct. My mistake.

Comment: @TheCount It depends greatly on what the OP's definition of partition _is_. You might be right, and this $F$ is completely fine. It's difficult to tell.

Comment: @Arthur yeah that's why I originally commented the way I did. Who knows?

Answer (score 5):

You compare it with the definition of *partition*. Is it a set of subsets of $E$? No: $c$ is an *element* of $E$, not a subset. Therefore $F$ cannot be a partition of $E$.